# iFrame app no longer working

Tags: facebook, session, iframe

I have a simple Facebook App that used to work in the old API. It's an iFrame app and I can't get the user session with the new API no matter what I try. Here is the code I have now.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
if ( !$session )
{
 //echo "Failed. No session.<br />";

    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
               'canvas' => 1,
               'fbconnect' => 0,
               'next'=>'http://www.facebook.com',
               'cancel_url' => 'http://www.facebook.com'
           ));

    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
    echo "<a href='".$url."' target='_blank'>First time using this App? Click here to connect it to your Facebook.</a>";

}
else {

    try {

        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        $updated = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($me['updated_time']));

        echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . "<br />";
        echo "You last updated your profile on " . $updated;

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);

    }
}
```

I've tried various things but $session is never returned (after clicking the link). I am using the correct appID/secret/facebook.php but it always falls into the !$session if path. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can this be related to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7181212/facebook-https-php-mistake ?

Comment: ^ I don't think so, I don't use SSL on my site/domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use new version of php-sdk (3.1.1) :)

Your code uses old sdk (in new there is no getSession method) and you probably have migration setting "OAuth Migration" set to true.

Comment: I'll try that out. Is there anything I can do to test and make sure this is the problem? I don't want to have to rewrite the code and still find it not working.

Comment: You can try to change your migration app settings. But you must switch to new sdk till October 1, 2011 anyway, so better now.